# Determine Class from Eigenclass

Tags: ruby, class, metaprogramming, eigenclass

In Ruby, getting the eigenclass of a class `Foo` is a simple as

```
eigenclass = class << Foo; self; end
#=> #<Class:Foo>
eigenclass = Foo.singleton_class #2.1.0
#=> #<Class:Foo>
```

I'm interested in the inverse operation: getting the owner of the eigenclass from the eigenclass itself:

```
klass = eigenclass.owner
#=> Foo
```

I'm not sure if this is possible, given that the eigenclass is an anonymous subclass of `Class`, so `Foo` appears nowhere in its inheritance hierarchy. Inspecting the method list of the eigenclass isn't encouraging either. `eigenclass.name` returns `nil`. The only thing that gives me hope this is possible:

```
Class.new # normal anon class
#=> #<Class:0x007fbdc499a050>
Foo.singleton_class
#=> #<Class:Foo>
```

Clearly, the eigenclass's `to_s` method knows *something* about the owner, even if this information is hardcoded when the eigenclass is instantiated. Therefore the only method I'm aware of is some hacky `Object.const_getting` from that like

```
Object.const_get eigenclass.to_s[/^#\<Class\:(?<owner>.+)\>$/, :owner]
#=> Foo
```

Comment: More succinctly:  Given the value of `"foo".singleton_class`, how can we get back to `"foo"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refining @BroiSatse's answer in a ruby-implementation-agnostic way,

```
class A; end
class B < A; end
class C < A; end
eigenclass = A.singleton_class
ObjectSpace.each_object(eigenclass).find do |klass|
  klass.singleton_class == eigenclass
end
#=> A
```

This is also reliable when handling branches in subclass trees, the only reason why @Andrew Marshall's elegant answer doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`ObjectSpace.each_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-each_object) passing it the singleton class to find all classes that match the given singleton class:

```
Klass = Class.new
ObjectSpace.each_object(Klass.singleton_class).to_a  #=> [Klass]
```

However, since a class’s singleton class inherits from its superclass’s singleton class, you’ll get multiple results if the class you’re trying to find has subclasses:

```
A = Class.new
B = Class.new(A)
B.singleton_class.ancestors.include?(A.singleton_class)  #=> true

candidates = ObjectSpace.each_object(A.singleton_class)
candidates.to_a  #=> [A, B]
```

Fortunately, [classes/modules are sortable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) by their place in the inheritance tree (same order [`ancestors`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-ancestors) gives). Since we know all the results must be part of the same inheritance tree, we can take the [`max`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max) to get the correct class:

```
candidates.sort.last  #=> A
ObjectSpace.each_object(B.singleton_class).max  #=> B
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if there's a branch in the inheritance tree: 

`class A; end; class B < A; end; class C < A; end`

`ObjectSpace.each_object(A.singleton_class).to_a #=> [C, B, A]`

`ObjectSpace.each_object(A.singleton_class).sort #=> ArgumentError: comparison of Class with Class failed`

Comment: @ChrisKeele Hmm, interesting. I don’t think there’s really an elegant way around that issue unfortunately. It fails, of course, because it doesn’t know whether to put `B` before `C` or vice-versa. Given that, I think that your own answer is probably the most reliable without being over-engineered.

Comment: It's looking like it. TIL that Modules are sortable though, which is super nifty in other metaprogramming contexts.

Comment: I'm wondering how that compare-function is actually implemented? I mean it's only a partial order, so a comparison-based sort intuitively won't work. But `Enumerable#sort` is comparison-based, right? It must be kind of hackily color the subtrees and lexicographically compare tuples of colors. Kinda strange.

Comment: According to the [`Module#<=>` docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) it returns `nil` if the two modules have no relation or the comparison isn't possible. I imagine ancestors of equal depth are in the latter category, and `Enumerable#sort` raises an error if `<=>` doesn't return `-1`, `0`, or `1`.

Comment: Andrew, some prefer `max` to `sort.last`. :-)

Comment: @ChrisKeele: Ah, so it just fails if the items don't form an inheritance chain :) I'm glad to hear that, it would have to be an uber-hacky compare function otherwise :P

Comment: @CarySwoveland Good point, not sure why that simplification escaped me when writing this—I prefer it too. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ObjectSpace`:

```
e = class << 'foo'; self; end

ObjectSpace.each_object(e).first    #=> 'foo'
```

To get object from inside of eigenclass:

```
class << 'foo'
  puts ObjectSpace.each_object(self).first
end

#=> 'foo'
```

Comment: That's quite clever, but not 100% reliable:

`class A; end; class B < A; end; ObjectSpace.each_object(A.singleton_class).first #=> B`

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is because most implementations avoid instantiating eigenclasses until needed, so if `A` hasn't invoked its own eigenclass in its definition, it first gets called when subclassing `B`.

Comment: Which ruby version are you using, I am still getting A running code above.

Comment: I'm on MRI 2.1.0-p0 ATM.